# В 'on_raw_reaction_remove' в 'payload.member' нет данных | Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Где *!* я скрыл id и имена с названиями.

В `on_raw_reaction_add` в параметре `payload` у меня передается информация:

```
<RawReactionActionEvent message_id=! user_id=! channel_id=! guild_id=! emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='' id=None> event_type='REACTION_ADD' member=<Member id=! name='Sarcandi' discriminator='!!!!' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=! name='!!!' shard_id=0 chunked=True member_count=9>>>
```

А в `on_raw_reaction_remove` в параметре `payload` передается только часть информации:

```
<RawReactionActionEvent message_id=! user_id=! channel_id=! guild_id=! emoji=<PartialEmoji animated=False name='' id=None> event_type='REACTION_REMOVE' member=None>
```

Я не могу понять. Почему в `on_raw_reaction_remove` в `payload.member` нет данных?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел на Хабр, непонятно почему разрабы так сделали ну что ж делать
https://qna.habr.com/q/897639

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)